# Cryptic result when crawling a site with simple html Dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom, web-crawler

I'm currenlty trying to gather some datas from politifact using simple html dom, but a lot of the time I have weirds errors instead of the html expected.
The goal is not to bruteforce the site but to request it once or twice a day and cache the result.
Here most of the returns I get :

```
‹������í]{wÛ6²ÿ»=g¿ªn#»1EËJœÄ–µ×vœ&ÙÄñÚn²{r{|(  ’S$Ã‡euÛï~3à¤¨‡c'ÛísNÄ`f0˜Úß=}sxþ¯“#1ŠÆŽ8ùùàÕ‹CQ3Ló]ëÐ4Ÿž?ÿ|~þú•h66Åy`¹¡Ùžk9¦yt\µQù;¦9™L“...
```

And here's the super simple code :

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.politifact.com/personalities/barack-obama');
print_r($html->plaintext);
```

Do you have any ideas why ?
Some sort of protection/redirection on the website side ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You received the expected page, but in gzip format. It looks like the server doesn't mind if the `accept-encoding` header is not included in the request and instead of sending a default plain text response, sends a gzipped data anyway.

I don't think simple-html-dom can unzip the data, but you can use cURL for that purpose:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.politifact.com/personalities/barack-obama/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');

$data = curl_exec($ch);

$html = str_get_html($data);
```

Comment: This looks perfect !
But right now cURL is returning an empty string, really weird o_O

Comment: Ahah just because I was missing an ending slash !
That did the trick, thank you so much !